# I have to show value from text view of one activity to another but when i load the first activity back the previous set data lost

Tags: android

main activity:

```
public void ifHangerButtonAction(View view)
    { 
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FastingHanger.class);
       startActivity(intent); 
    }

protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("globalVariable.getFastingHourValue()="+globalVariable.getFastingHourValue());
        if(globalVariable.getFastingHourValue()!=null)
        {
            intended_fast_image_view.setText(globalVariable.getFastingHourValue());
           System.out.println("config_text_view="+config_text_view);
        }
       else 
           intended_fast_image_view.setText("00:00");

        if(globalVariable.getName()!=null)
        {
            config_text_view.setText(globalVariable.getName());
        }
       else 
           config_text_view.setText("24"+" "+"/"+" "+"0");
        if(globalTimer.tv!=null)
        {
            actual_text_view.setText((CharSequence) globalTimer.tv);
        }
        else 
            actual_text_view.setText("00:00:00");

    }
```

second activity

```
public void homeScreen()
{
    globalVariable.setFastingHourValue(fastingHourValue);
    System.out.println("globalVariable.setFastingHourValue(fastingHourValue)="+fastingHourValue);
    globalVariable.setName(getName);
    System.out.println("globalVariable.setName(getName)="+getName);
    finish();

}
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

     if(globalVariable.getFastingHourValue()!=null)
        { 
            System.out.println(" if globalVariable.getFastingHourValue()="+globalVariable.getFastingHourValue());
            image_view3.setText(globalVariable.getFastingHourValue());
            System.out.println("on resume");
        }
       else {
           System.out.println(" else globalVariable.getFastingHourValue()="+globalVariable.getFastingHourValue());
           image_view3.setText("24:00");
       }

        if(globalVariable.getStartingTime()=="00:00")
        {
            start_image_view.setText(globalVariable.getStartingTime());
        }
        else 
            start_image_view.setText("00:00");
        if(globalVariable.getEndingTime()!=null)
        {
            end_image_view.setText(globalVariable.getEndingTime());
        }
        else
            end_image_view.setText("00:00");
        if(globalVariable.getFeedingTimeValue()=="00:00")
        {
            image_view4.setText(globalVariable.getFeedingTimeValue());
        }
        else
        image_view4.setText("00:00");
//rs
        if(globalVariable.getFastingHourValue()==image_view3.getText().toString())
        {

            System.out.println("image_view3 globalVariable.getFastingHourValue()="+globalVariable.getFastingHourValue());
            image_view3.setText(globalVariable.getFastingHourValue());
        }
     MyApplication.activityResumed();
     System.out.println( "in resume of fasting hanger");

}
```

Comment: declare the variable as global or pass the data between the activity.

Comment: declared global variable but getting null value in the variable after resuming to second activity

Comment: then pass the data between the activity using bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Pass value using bundle...

```
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("key", value);

                    Intent loginIntent = new Intent();
                    loginIntent.putExtras(b);
                    loginIntent.setClass(MainActivity.this,TestActivity.class);
```

and then get data in next activity like this..

```
    Bundle b3 = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String txt= b3.getString("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data between activities like :

In MainActivity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, Other_Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID", "SOME DATAS");
startActivity(intent);
```

In Other_Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
String datas= extras.getString("EXTRA_ID");
if (datas!= null) {
   // do stuff
}        
}
```

Also Check this : [Android Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can Pass the data values by using Bundle also as like

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("key", value);                             
Intent loginIntent = new Intent();
loginIntent.putExtras(b);
loginIntent.setClass(MainActivity.this,TestActivity.class);
```

And also you can do this by using singleton object

#### what the documentation is suggesting is to use a normal singleton pattern like

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

```
public class SingletonDemo {
    private static SingletonDemo instance = null;

    private SingletonDemo() {       }

    public static SingletonDemo getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                  if (instance == null) {
                        instance = new SingletonDemo ();
                  }
            }
            return instance;
    }
}
```

and include inside it a method like this:

```
private Context context;
 init(Context context){
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
 }
```

and remember to call this to initialise the singleton.

The difference between the Application approach and the Singleton approach and why the Singleton is better is on the documentation same functionality in a more modular way